# Printing an hexadecimal memory address of a node in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list which takes an input string and stores each string in a node of the list. I want to print the hexadecimal address of the node where each string is saved.

How can i do that? I tried printing the hex address of the saved word, but i don't know yet if it's still the same address of the node, this is the function supposed to print each node:

```
// print the list
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
{ 
   // if list is empty
   if (isEmpty(currentPtr)) {
      puts("List is empty.\n");
   } 
   else { 
      puts("The list is:");
      // while not the end of the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         printf("%s %p --> ", currentPtr->data, &currentPtr);

         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;   
      } 
      puts("NULL\n");
   } 
}
```

This is the function that saves each word in a node

```
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value)
{ 
   ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)+1); // create node

   if (newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
      newPtr->data= malloc(strlen(value));
      strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...               
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node 
      }                                          
      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("Not inserted. No memory available.\n" );
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` has either too few arguments or too many `%s`es.

Comment: Beside the point of your post: you need `malloc(strlen(value)+1);` for the null termination at the end of the string. You should run valgrind in order to find more errors of this type in your code.

Comment: address of the `currentPtr->data` is an address of the saved word

Comment: Other than that, you want to print the value of the pointer, not the address of the variable that holds the pointer, so: `printf("%s %p --> ", currentPtr->data, currentPtr);`. Also, you have an extra %s for no reason.

Comment: So you can print address of your word like: `printf("word address %p of current node: %p", currentPtr->data, currentPtr);`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&currentPtr` give you a pointer to the pointer *variable*, it's not where `currentPtr` is actually pointing. The value of `&currentPtr` will not change in the loop, since the variable itself will not change location.

If you want to print where `currentPtr` is pointing, to the node itself, then print plain `currentPtr`.

Comment: It's clear now! I used %p, currentPtr and i'm getting the hex address, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the prototype of `printList` below, we see that `currentPtr` is already a pointer to `ListNode` (assuming `ListNodePtr` is a `typedef` of `ListNode*`).

```
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
```

So you can just print `currentPtr` for the address of the node.

> I tried printing the hex address of the saved word, but i don't know yet if it's still the same address of the node

The node address will also be the address of the saved word **only if the saved word is the first element** of the `ListNode` structure.